# Deal with segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to solve a CodeChef problem. Whenever I run it I get a segmentation fault. This is the link to the problem: [Malvika is peculiar about color of balloons](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHN09)

Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>

int main(){
    std::string balloonColors;
    size_t numberOfAmber;
    size_t numberOfBrass;
    int t;
    int results[t];

    std::cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        int result = 0;
        std::cin >> balloonColors;
        numberOfAmber = std::count(balloonColors.begin(), balloonColors.end(), 'a');
        numberOfBrass = std::count(balloonColors.begin(), balloonColors.end(), 'b');

        if (numberOfAmber == 0 || numberOfBrass == 0){
            result = 0;
        }

        if (numberOfAmber <= numberOfBrass){
            result = (int)numberOfAmber;
        }
        else {
            result = (int)numberOfBrass;    
        }

        results[i] = result;

    }
    for (int x = 0; x < t; x++){
        std::cout << results[x] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You use the debugger and step through your program line by line, until the segfault occurs. Then check all of your variables values at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines is the problem:

```
int t;
int results[t];
```

You declare `results` using the *uninitialized* variable `t`. An uninitialized variable have an *indeterminate* value, and using it before initialization leads to *undefined behavior*.

You should use a `std::vector` here, and set its size once you get the actual size from the user:

```
int t;
std::vector<int> results;

std::cin >> t;

results.resize(t);
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C++ need to have a fixed size. You defined `results` with size `t`, which isn't fixed.

To use dynamic size, use a `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <vector>
...
int t;
std::cin >> t;
std::vector<int> results (t);
```